# Find row with value "0" in column then SUM row with row above

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make an Excel macro that searches `Sheets("Data").Range("B:" & lastRow)` for the value "0".

If it finds a row with the value "0" in column B I need it to SUM and merge the row with the row above it.

I have the code below, but I'm getting errors and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong:

```
Sub sumZeroRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    With ws

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow To 11 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "0" Then
                .Cells(i - 1, "C").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "C").Value2 + .Cells(i, "C").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "D").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "D").Value2 + .Cells(i, "D").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "E").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "E").Value2 + .Cells(i, "E").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "F").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "F").Value2 + .Cells(i, "F").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "G").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "G").Value2 + .Cells(i, "G").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "H").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "H").Value2 + .Cells(i, "H").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "I").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "I").Value2 + .Cells(i, "I").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "J").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "J").Value2 + .Cells(i, "J").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "K").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "K").Value2 + .Cells(i, "K").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "L").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "L").Value2 + .Cells(i, "L").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "M").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "M").Value2 + .Cells(i, "M").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "N").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "N").Value2 + .Cells(i, "N").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "O").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "O").Value2 + .Cells(i, "O").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "P").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "P").Value2 + .Cells(i, "P").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "Q").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "Q").Value2 + .Cells(i, "Q").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "R").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "R").Value2 + .Cells(i, "R").Value2
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

My cells looks like [image: this].

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  If you have code please include it in your original post.  We will help resolve specific problems with existing code.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty straightforward `If()` statement. What have you tried? If you're able to get a `LastRow`, then you should be able to work out how to write your statement. Please show us your efforts, and what has/hasn't worked.

Comment: I apologize, got an error when i tried to add code. I have edited my post with the code :)

Comment: How will you merge the rows? What do your rows look like? The `Sum` part is simple, but how can we merge the rows? Say we're going to merge rows 1 and 2 - would you simply add the info from `A1` into `A2`, `B1` into `B2`, with some delimiter?

Comment: Along with the code it would be helpful if you showed some test data and expected outcome.

Comment: I've added a picture :) The numbers in the two rows need to be SUM'ed and then merged into one row.

Comment: _"but I'm getting errors"_  - please post the relevant parts of the error(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
Sub sumZeroRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    With ws

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow To 11 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "0" Then
                .Cells(i - 1, "C").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "C").Value2 + .Cells(i, "C").Value2
                .Cells(i - 1, "D").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "D").Value2 + .Cells(i, "D").Value2
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

You need to loop backwards when deleting rows.  And sum each column individually.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was trying to do :)

Comment: Though, when I run it, i get a Run-time Error '13' - Type mismatch. Do you have an idea as to what it could be? It highlights the first line with .Cells(i - 1, "C").Value.

Comment: Then your times are text that look like time not numbers with a mask of time.  You will need to go through and make them all times not text. @MichaelLengsø

Comment: Hello Scott.

I've tried changing them all to time instead of text, but I still get a mismatch.